# Can I redirect a PHP page from HTDOCS to a Python page that is from django?

Tags: python, php

is it possible for me to redirect a python page from django from a php? 
just asking because i already did the php page in advance using xampp and i did a code using python from django but i want to connect the 2 pages together without re-writing the code..

i tried doing this in my php page:

```
<?php 
 if (isset($_POST['submit']))
 {
   #exec('python ../views.py ' );
   header("Location: ../views.py");
 }
?>
```

but the button wont redirect to any page.. but i already check the directory of the file and it is correct, and the server for python is already running

Comment: You can't call views.py directly, you have to call a URL in Django.

Comment: how do i do that?